# sending messages to everyone with discord python bot discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

How can i dm every user in every guild my bot is in without using user ids? Here is some code I have tried but it didn't work:

```
user = client.get_user(user_id) 
await user.send('Hello')
```

Comment: You can simply use a `for` loop, here is an example ```for user in client.users: await user.send("Hello!")```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do here, But if you want to message all users in every server your bot is in you can do this:

```
for user in client.users:
    try:
        await user.send("Hello!")
    except:
        pass #incase they have dms off
```

I would highly recommend not doing this, as it will annoy members and server owners!

Comment: You can also loop through `Client.users` or `Client.get_all_members`  to avoid a nested loop

Comment: the code did not work and i tried to print member 'print(member)' and it only grabbed my own bot's name from every server

Comment: nvm i fixed it by enabling inits

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński ofc, forgot about that. ill edit it right now.